# ensuring unique session variables in .NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0, .net-4.6

I have a website, running on IIS and .NET 4.6, that gets about 80 to 100 concurrent users at any given time.

I want to create a session variable for each user that looks like this:

```
Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("IsSecuredArea")
```

This variable is set to False as a default value and also set to False in both the **Session_End** sub and the **Application_End** sub inside the **Global.asax.vb** file.

I set this variable to true after the user logs in successfully and pulling data from a database and populating a unique dataset for that user.

I set it like this:

```
Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("IsSecuredArea") = True
```

My question is, how can I make sure that this session variable is unique for each user?

I don't want one user seeing the secured area of another user by accident.

Thanks!

Comment: The session is unique to each active session of a user - so there's no need to make the variable name unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are safe. Session value will not be shared across users.